# PHP if with fetch from Mysql DB

Tags: php

I can't get my head around why this wont work..

```
<?
(connect info and select DB etc here)

$term = $_POST['term'];
$sql = mysql_query("select * from evansu where username like '%$term%'");
 if ($row==$term)
    {
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))

      echo 'ID: '.$row['ID'];
    echo '<br/> First Name: '.$row['username'];
    echo '<br/> Last Name: '.$row['name'];
    echo '<br/> Phone: '.$row['Phone'];
    echo '<br/><br/>';
}

else
  echo "Nothing found, have a nice day!";
```

?>

It says nothing found even if the value is in the DB, and if I remove the if code it works and shows the info. Help?

Answer (score 3):

`$row==$term` is `false` if `$_POST['term']` is not empty. This leads to the `while` loop not being executed.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not indented properly and you forgot braces for the while.
Also you mixed up the loops.

```
$term = $_POST['term'];
$sql = mysql_query("select * from evansu where username like '%$term%'");
$row = NULL

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{ if ($row['username']==$term)
    {
      echo 'ID: '.$row['ID'];
      echo '<br/> First Name: '.$row['username'];
      echo '<br/> Last Name: '.$row['name'];
      echo '<br/> Phone: '.$row['Phone'];
      echo '<br/><br/>';
    }
}
if (!$row)
{  echo "Nothing found, have a nice day!"; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have declared nowhere the variable $row so that you can check against it. So, you basically are checking against a non-existent variable. You should declare the row earlier in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You should have `$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)` before checking if your `$row['username'] == $term`